# Databinding ListViewer(Based on combo selection listviewer should be undated with list values)

Tags: java, data-binding, swt, jface

This is my first question in this forum. I have been trying to create data binding between Combo viewer and List Viewer. My query is 
If I select a values in the Combo Viewer I need to update a list of values in the ListViewer. Listviewer values has to be changed based on combo selection. All values are of type String

Please check my code I have written

```
//Dialog Code
//Assume I created a contentcomposite already

ComboViewer comboViewer = new ComboViewer(parent, SWT.READ_ONLY);        
comboViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
comboViewer.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider());       
comboViewer.setInput(importModel.getcViewerList()); //will get values for 
combo viewer

ListViewer listViewer = new ListViewer(parent);
listViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
listViewer.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider());


//Model Class

public class TestModel {

private Collection<String> testList = new ArrayList<>();

private String testValue1;

public Collection<String> gettestList() {
    return testList;
}

public void settestList(Collection<String> teslist) {
    this.vehicleClassesList = teslist;
}
}
```

Comment: Just using a Selection Changed listener on the combo viewer would be simplest

Comment: Thanks for the reply is there any way without using listener. By using Databinding.